# Unable to avoid duplicate insertion in database

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have a table in which i am adding values to it, i want to avoid all duplicate insert in my table,

Here is my query:

```
INSERT INTO Categories (Name, Image) VALUES ("Womens Fashion", "http://static.abcd.com/images/nw-cat12-big.png") WHERE Name="Womens Fashion" not in
(
   SELECT Name from Categories WHERE Name="Womens Fashion"
)
```

error message: near "WHERE" syntax error.

**Please help and thanks in advance.**

Comment: create a unique index.

Comment: What is desired logic? I can't understand what you're trying to achieve with your query

Comment: I want to avoid duplicate insertion in column called `Name`

Comment: How to create unique index in column called `Name`

Comment: Add unique index that will do it for you
try something like this:
ALTER TABLE `Categories` ADD UNIQUE INDEX (`Name`);

Comment: Shows syntax error near "UNIQUE"

Comment: I believe you are on MySQL 5+ server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO table1 
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT 'Womens Fashion'                                 name, 
               'http://static.abcd.com/images/nw-cat12-big.png' images)t1 
WHERE  t1.name NOT IN (SELECT name 
                       FROM   table1);
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66a09/1)

Comment: Superb dude, it works

Comment: Yes, it works my friend.

Comment: Nevertheless it is the wrong way to do it. The relevant key should be defined as UNIQUE.

Comment: Thanks for your comment,but i just answer the question, and i did n't say that is it good or bad way.